# How to remove Size filter section from layered navigation in magento 1.9.01

Tags: magento-1.9

How to remove **Price filter** from layered navigation? I set Layered Navigation in Manage Attribute section size as 0 but still the Size filter is showing in left side under Shop by section.

Can anyone assist me resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > edit size attribute

set **Use In Layered Navigation** to **No**

[image]

Comment: Nope.. did not work..

Answer (score 0):

Find this file in out layout folder of your theme.

```
/app/design/frontend/diakart/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

there find the layout file written for layered navigation.

check code like this line, For size also you will get same line.

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```

add this line before `</block>` ends.

```
<action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
```

Comment: Nope.. did not work..

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Catalog > Manage Attributes > Attribute
2. Then search size attribute here in the grid and click on it
3. Now for this attribute make Use In Layered Navigation to No.

Save and clear cache

Comment: Nope.. did not work..

Answer (score 0):

> got to admin panel catalog > attribute > manage attribute and set your
>   current attribute to Use In Layered Navigation to no

**OR**

It can be done either by just be using category layout updates.

Open the category edit page, switch to the "Custom Design" tab, and put the code in the "Custom Layout Update" field.

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav"><action method="unsetChild"><alias>shoes_size_filter</alias></action></reference>
```

Answer (score -1):

First confirm what you want to remove **Price** filter or **Size** filter.
Any attribute you want to remove from layered navigation then just go to

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Edit that attribute

[image]

and set 'Use In Layered Navigation' to **No**

Comment: This answer was already posted why did you post this again?

Comment: This might be difference of some fraction of time while posting this answer.

Comment: None of the above solutions works for me.. bot the price and color filter still remains on the layered navigation